# I have to apply geoNear pipeline on location but have to filter users? How this will be achieved?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregates

I am filtering users based on some attributes in the user collection and based on coordinates present in the location collection as in the below code. I have to Filter the location radius after the match pipeline because it will reduce the number of documents to populate. But I am getting this error I'm not getting any points on how to cope with this. Error: $geoNear is only valid as the first stage in a pipeline.

One thing more, I have to lookup up locations first, to apply the geoNear query on this. Or if there is any better sequence to do let me know. And if I'm not wrong I am applying geoNear on users' collections, which should be on locations collections.

Code:

```js
     if (locationRange) {
        const coordinates = user.location.coordinates.coordinates;
        locationFilter = {
          near: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [coordinates[0], coordinates[1]],
          },
          distanceField: "distance",
          maxDistance: locationRange.max,
          minDistance: locationRange.min,
          spherical: true
        };
      }
    
      const res = await User.aggregate([
        {
          $match: match,
        },
        {
         $lookup: {
            from: 'locations',
            localField: 'location',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'location',
          },
        },
        {
          $unwind: {
            path: '$location',
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
          },
        },
        { ...(Object.keys(locationFilter).length && { $geoNear: locationFilter }) },
        { $skip: (page - 1) * limit },
        { $sort: sortingOptions },
        { $limit: limit },
          ]);
```

I am trying to filter users based on their role and some other attributes. Also want to filter based on their location.

Comment: @ray thanks for editing the code. I'm quite new to posting questions.